# Find area of right triangle △ with circumcircle $O$ and tangent circle $K$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

The triangle $ABC$, with $\angle A = 90^\circ$,
is inscribed in the circle $\mathcal{O}$.
The circle $\mathcal{K}$ is tangent to the circle $\mathcal{O}$,
the sides $AB$ and $AC$.
Suppose that the radius of $\mathcal{O}$ is $3$
and the radius of $\mathcal{K}$ is $2$. Find the area of $\triangle ABC$.

I drew this problem out by making circle $\mathcal{K}$
internally tangent to circle $\mathcal{O}$.
I was able to make it tangent to $AB$ and $AC$.
However, I have gotten nowhere using trigonometry to solve this.

I also tried to name the sides and angles
to find the area, which did not work, either

Comment: $$Area_{ABC}=7$$

Comment: @Raffaele could you please explain your thought process?

Comment: https://imgur.com/za5Xte4

Comment: @Raffaele so did you draw this on a coordinate plane and find the area by finding the intersection of the circles and lines? Or was there a solution using theorems and logic?

Comment: Totally graphical. I could not find an answer, otherwise I'd written this as an answer. I thought that having the result and the drawing could help

Comment: @Raffaele how did you know that the triangle you drew was the correct triangle to use? There are no given side lengths, so technically aren't there an infinite number of triangles that could be drawn?

Comment: No, there is only one. With GeoGebra you can adjust precisely until the smaller circle touches the triangle sides and the larger circle. And there is only one triangle which satisfies this property. But I couldn't prove it: I just view it graphically

Comment: @Raffaele correct me if I'm wrong but any right triangle inscribed in a circle has the diameter as it hypotenuse. There are an infinite amount of right triangles that can be created by dragging the vertex along the arc equal to 180 degrees.

Comment: Yes, but this is what happens https://imgur.com/Dtzfx6D

Comment: @Raffaele would it be possible for you to send the equations?

Comment: Don't think they are useful, anyway https://imgur.com/hvW9d44

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Start with arbitrary point $L$ on the circle $\mathcal{O}(O,R)$
and draw the circle $\mathcal{K}(K,r_k)$,
tangent to $\mathcal{O}(O,R)$
at $L$.

Let $L=(0,-R)$, $K=(0,-R+r_k)$.

Since $\mathcal{K}$ is inscribed in $\angle CAB$,
and $\angle CAB=90^\circ$, the distance $|KA|=r_k\sqrt{2}$,
so we can find the point $A$ as the intersection of
the $\mathcal{O}$
and the circle centered at $K$ with the radius $r_k\sqrt2$.

$AK$ is the bisector of $\angle CAB$, hence
the tangent point $D= AB\cap \mathcal{K}$
can be easily found, as $\triangle ADK$ is isosceles.

When $R=3$, $r_k=2$, $\triangle OKA$ is right angled,
since in this case $|OK|^2+|KA|^2=|OA|^2=R^2=9$,
which means that

\begin{align} 
|AD|=|KD|&=r_k=2
,\\
|OE|&=\frac{r_k}{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2
,\\
|DE|&=\frac{r_k}{\sqrt2}-(R-r_k)=\sqrt2-1
,\\
|OD|&=
\sqrt{R^2-(2+\sqrt2)\,r_k\,(R-r_k)}
=\sqrt{5-2\sqrt2}
.
\end{align}

Then consider $\triangle ABO$,
for which we already know values of $AD$, $|OD|$
and also that $|OB|=|OA|=3$, so we can apply
[the Stewart’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)

\begin{align} 
\triangle ABO:\quad
&|OB|^2\cdot|AD|+|OA|^2
\cdot(|AB|-|AD|)
\\
&=
|AB|\cdot(|OD|^2+|AD|\cdot(|AB|-|AD|))
,
\end{align}

which gives the unique solution: $|AB|=4+\sqrt2$.
Then
\begin{align} 
|AC|&=\sqrt{4R^2-|AB|^2}
=4-\sqrt2
\end{align}

and the sought area then is

\begin{align} 
S_{ABC}&=\tfrac12\,|AB|\cdot|AC|=
\tfrac12(16-2)=7
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to assume a special case for which the second circle information is superfluous.

For example, inscribe a square into circle O with a corner at point A. Then, per [a source](https://geometryhelp.net/square-inscribed-in-a-circle/), to quote:

> We can show this using a symmetry argument – the square is symmetrical across its diagonal, so the diagonal must pass through the center of the circle.

The diagonal line also creates two right triangles, one at Point A. So, with a hypotenuse of 6 (as the radius is given as 3), the sides of the triangle (and square) are ${3\sqrt{2}}$.

This implies an area of the square of 18 sq units and for the triangle, as one possible answer for the question, 9 sq units.

Comment: Good idea. However, will this always work? Also are you talking about it being a 45-45-90 triangle?

Comment: No,  clearly a special case. Does the original question source imply a general solution? If not, it may be because it actually does not exist. My answer, however, does display some knowledge of the properties of inscribed figures, which may be the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Note that BK $=2\sqrt2$, the diagonal of the square of side length $2$ and $\triangle$BOK is a right triangle because of its sides, $1$, $2\sqrt2$ and $3$, satisfying the Pythagorean rule. Then, $\sin\theta =\frac{KO}{BO}= \frac13$ and
$$\sin\alpha \cos\alpha = \sin(45-\theta)\cos(45-\theta)=\frac{1}2\cos2\theta=\frac12-\sin^2\theta=\frac7{18}
$$
Thus, the area of $\triangle$ABC is
$$Area_{ABC}=\frac12AB\cdot BC=\frac12AC^2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha = \frac12\cdot6^2\cdot\frac7{18}=7
$$